# Parallel execution using iterator as feed

Tags: r

I am trying to use an iterator such that the `foreach::foreach` function will take element by element from the iterator and pass it to the available worker.

From testing it seems that the `foreach::foreach` function first lists the whole iterator in the main thread, and then passes the elements to the workers. I have traced this to the following line of code:

```
argsList <- as.list(it)
results <- clusterApplyLB(cl, argsList, evalWrapper)
```

within the `doParallel::e$fun()`.

Now I don't get it. What is the point of allowing iterators if you will store its items into `argsList`?

According to the `foreach` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf) (cf. section 4) the iterator should work element by element and should not be converted to a list. Can someone help me with this? I am probably doing something wrong.

#### Example 1

One can reproduce this relatively easily. Define a function like

```
testing <- function(){sample(0:9, 4, replace=TRUE)}
```

Convert it to an iterator (cf. [here](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/iterators/vignettes/iterators.pdf)):

```
iterator <- iterators::iter(testing)
```

And then feed this to the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach::foreach(element = iterator) %dopar% ...
```

Obviously my real iterator has an end and can, unlike this example, be `as.list()`-ed. But it doesn't fit into memory.

#### Example 2

Suppose this data `x`.

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(1e+06), ncol = 10000)
```

Suppose it doesn't fit into memory - and certainly not when sent to multiple workers - so we use an iterator instead:

```
itx <- iterators::iter(x, by = "row")
foreach(i = itx, .combine = c) %dopar% mean(i)
```

I expect now that each row of this matrix will be taken 1-at-a-time from the iterator, and sent to the available worker. But what seems to be happening is that this iterator gets unpacked into the object `argsList` in the main thread and then each element gets sent to the worker. This is what happens:

```
foreach(i = lapply(itx, list), .combine = c) %dopar% mean(i[[1]])
```

The whole point of an iterator is not to clog up memory, while here that is exactly what is happening. `lapply(itx, list)` doesn't fit into memory!

#### Workaround

My workaround up till now is to take as many as possible elements from the iterator, and feed them to the `foreach` loop. Repeat until the iterator is empty. Obviously I am more interested in the real solution.

Comment: What do you think is your `iterator` list? What do you expect as output here? Use `i*i` as the function you pass to each core...

Comment: @ChiPak Example added.

Answer (score -1):

Example 2: Let me rewrite your code as I would do it:

```
x <- matrix(1:10, ncol=2)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
```

To evaluate the mean of each row of the matrix:

```
foreach(I=1:nrow(x)) %dopar% mean(x[I,])
```

This will pass `x[I,]` to each worker and evaluate the `mean`, which is returned to the `parent`. You are correct; this will absolutely **NOT** improve the speed of the evaluation, compared to `apply(x, 1, mean)`. `foreach` and `parallel` give you the most speedup when each evaluation (iteration) takes a long time and therefore serial (single-core) execution is slow. (Multi-core execution requires additional overhead to communicate between workers...)  Multi-core execution will **NOT** aid in memory usage.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I don't want to pass iterators to workers. I want to pass elements of one iterator to workers (load-balanced). So after a worker finishes, it takes a new element from the main thread. Check my extra-info edit.